# CSS Grid Layout. Row that contains a logo may be set or maybe not

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have this grid layout.

The `nav` and `footer` areas takes up the whole space between column 1 and column 4.

The `header`, `main` and `aside` takes  up only the space between column 2 and column 3.

[image]

The `header` will just hold a logo. However I design for a CMS and that logo might be set, might be not, depending on the user. By default there is no logo set but what should I do with that empty `header` area in grid when logo is not set?

Please check the full page view:

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto) 1fr;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.nav {
  background: #0e9daf;
}

.main {
  background: #9e9e9e;
}

.header {
  background: #6F9C1B;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #dd9f32;
}

.footer {
  align-self: end;
  background: #9b51e0;
}

@media (min-width: 52em) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns:
      minmax(0, 1fr)
      minmax(0, 50em)
      minmax(0, 20em)
      minmax(0, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto) 1fr;
  }

  .grid-container > * {
    grid-column: 1/-1;
  }

  .main {
    grid-column: 2;
  }

  .sidebar {
    grid-column: 3;
  }

  .header {
    grid-column: 2/4;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test-layout.css">
  <title>CSS Grid Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <nav class="nav">
      Nav
    </nav>

    <header class="header">
      Logo
    </header>

    <main class="main">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </main>

    <aside class="sidebar">
      Sidebar
    </aside>

    <footer class="footer">
      Footer
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This CSS is responsible for the rows on larger screens:

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto) 1fr;
```

So there are 4 rows in total. However, what will happen if the user don't upload a logo? which means there will be nothing (no content) in the second row (the `header` row). Should I just let the `header` row there regardless if the logo is the set or not?

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto) 1fr;
```

Any suggestion would be appreciate. Thank you!

Comment: it's just fine, if header is empty , it will be 0px of height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the height of that row is auto simply set the position of each element explicitely and it would be good. That row will be empty (height = 0) when the logo is not there.

Add/remove `header` element to compare

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto) 1fr;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.nav {
  background: #0e9daf;
}

.main {
  background: #9e9e9e;
  grid-row:3; /* added */
}

.header {
  background: #6F9C1B;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #dd9f32;
  grid-row: 4; /* added */
}

.footer {
  align-self: end;
  background: #9b51e0;
  grid-row: 5; /* added */
}

@media (min-width: 52em) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns:
      minmax(0, 1fr)
      minmax(0, 50em)
      minmax(0, 20em)
      minmax(0, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto) 1fr auto;
  }

  .grid-container > * {
    grid-column: 1/-1;
  }

  .main {
    grid-column: 2;
  }

  .sidebar {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row:3; /* added */
  }

  .header {
    grid-column: 2/4;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <nav class="nav">
      Nav
    </nav>

    <!--<header class="header">
      Logo
    </header>-->

    <main class="main">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </main>

    <aside class="sidebar">
      Sidebar
    </aside>

    <footer class="footer">
      Footer
    </footer>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your example confuses me a bit. If `grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto) 1fr auto;` is set why do I need to specify those rows explicitely. Also you're code didn't set anything for `nav`

Comment: @ZoltanKing nav is always on the top and the first element so no need anything for it since it's always at row = 1 ... for the others (excluding header) they need to start from row = 3 and row = 4 so we explicitely set this because if we don't do add the header is not there they will be shifted up and will start from row = 2

Comment: Shifting wouldn't be an issue. If header row 3 becomes row 2, I do not target those rows for special purposes.

Comment: @ZoltanKing it would be an issue because of the 1fr, run on full page the code and see the difference with and without header

Comment: Okay I understood that `nav` is the first but the `header` row doesn't need to bet set then to a value?

Comment: @ZoltanKing no, because like nav, it will automatically be placed at the second row since it's the second element after nav and nav is always there

Comment: Ok. One more question, the footer on large screens (the one in media) queries in theory should be on row 4, not the fifth as on mobile, however your code set it to 5th row regardless.

Comment: @ZoltanKing true, you can update it but it's not an issue since you will have the 4 row empty and it won't be visible. This can be an issue in case you are using gap where you will see the gap twice

Comment: If the `<header>` element is there all the time but only the content inside it is missing do I still need to use your method? I mean the `header` is there but no content.

Comment: @ZoltanKing no you don't need since the element is there. It will simply be empty and take its row which will also be empty